# Why does element.style.FontSize not work for classes that are iterated over which are before saved in an array made with querySelectorAll?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, class, dom, queryselector

Dear Stackoverflow Community,
Today i have an issue regarding javascript and also wordpress:
i have a js script named setDynamicFontHeight.js, a php document named header.php, a php document named navbar_mobile.php which is just doing wp_nav_menu(arguments) and a enquirement of the function via the functions.php in my wordpress theme. the arguments are just the location of the navbar and the wrapper class of the navbar.
In the setDynamicFontHeight.js i think the problem is after the *//set font height* comment.
The script is enquired correctly via the functions.php (alerts work) and the header.php is just markup with some wordpress functions.
What i want the js function setDynamicFontHeight(args) to do is that it should change a specific texts height to the height of a reference object. text and reference object can either be called by class or by id. Note that the function works perfectly on the Text named SiteTitle but it doesent work on the queryselector *mobileNavUl li*. i think the issue is with that query selector or the loop which processes the array made by the qs.
They look as follows:

**setDynamicFontHeight.js**

```
function setDynamicFontHeight 
(textToChange,referenceObject,classOrID,referenceObjectClassOrID){

//find out parent of textToChange

//handle class or id of textToChange and referenceObject
let textToChangeElement;
let referenceObjectSize;
switch (classOrID){
case "class": textToChangeElement = document.querySelector("."+textToChange);
break;
case "id": textToChangeElement = document.getElementById(textToChange);
break;
default: alert("Sie müssen für die Funktion setDynamicFontHeight im zweiten Argument angeben, ob der Text, dessen Höhe angepasst werden soll per ID(id) oder Klasse(class) angesprochen werden soll.");
break;
}
let textParentElement = textToChangeElement.parentElement;
//check for invalid arguments and for referenceObject = class or id. If ReferenceObject = null, then use parent element(default)
if(referenceObject == null){
referenceObjectSize = textParentElement;
}
else if (referenceObject != null && referenceObjectClassOrID == "class"){
referenceObjectSize = document.querySelector("."+referenceObject).offsetHeight;
}
else if (referenceObject != null && referenceObjectClassOrID == "id"){
referenceObjectSize = document.getElementById(referenceObject).offsetHeight;
}
else{
alert("Bitte geben sie die 4 Argumente für diese Funktion in der folgenden Reihenfolge an: textToChange,referenceObject,classOrID,referenceObjectClassOrID.");
}



//find out size of parent in vh
let viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;


//setting newFontHeightInVh

let newFontHeightInVh = (referenceObjectSize/viewportHeight*100*4/3);

//set font height
if(classOrID == "id"){
document.getElementById(textToChange).style.fontSize = (newFontHeightInVh+"vh");
}
else if(classOrID = "class"){
gotElementsOfClass = document.querySelectorAll(textToChange);
gotElementsOfClass.forEach(function(element) {
element.style.fontSize = (newFontHeightInVh+"vh");
});
}

}
//dynamic height for site title
setDynamicFontHeight("siteTitle","hamburger-box","id", "class");
setDynamicFontHeight("mobileNavUl li","siteTitle","class","class");
//dynamic height for the mobile navigation list
```

**header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title><?php wp_title('') ?></title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href='<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url')?>'>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./wp- 
content/themes/almondotheme/template_parts/hamburgers/dist/hamburgers.css">
<?php wp_head(); ?>

</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>
    <div class="sitewrapper">
        <header>
            <div class="header-sub-wrapper">

            <div class="mobilenavhamburger-wrapper">
            <button id="mobilenavhamburger"class="mobilenavhamburger hamburger 
            hamburger--spin" type="button">
                <span class="hamburger-box">
                    <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
                </span>
            </button>
            <div id = siteTitleWrapper>
                <h1 id ="siteTitle" class ="siteTitle">Almondo-Kaffee</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id= "mobilenavbar-wrapper" class="mobilenavbar-wrapper">
        <?php if(wp_is_mobile()){get_template_part("./template_parts/navbar_mobile",);
        }?>
    </div>

    <div class="mobilenavcontent">
    <div id = "headerTextPC">
    <h1 class="text-3xl"><a href="<?php echo home_url("/");?>"><?php 
    bloginfo("name")?></a></h1>
    <p><?php bloginfo("description")?></p>
    </div>
    </div>

</div>


</header>
```

**navbar_mobile.php**

```
<nav>
<?php
$argsformobilenavbar=array (
"theme_location" => "nav_mobile",
'menu_class'=> 'mobileNavUl',
);
wp_nav_menu($argsformobilenavbar);

?>
</nav>
```

**and the enquirement functions.php**

```
function setDynamicFontHeight() { 
wp_register_script('setDynamicFontHeight','./wp-content/themes/almondotheme/template_parts/scripts/setDynamicFontHeight.js',null,false,true);

wp_enqueue_script('setDynamicFontHeight','./wp-content/themes/almondotheme/template_parts/scripts/setDynamicFontHeight.js',null,false,true);
}

add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts","setDynamicFontHeight",10,0);
```

The Navbar structure is as follows:

```
<nav>
    <div class="mobileNavUl">
        <ul>
            <li class="page_item page-item-2" style="visibility: visible; opacity: 1;">
                <a href="http://almondo/beispiel-seite/">Beispiel-Seite
                </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
It was a missing concatenation of the reference Class with a dot.